# Apache Camel - What is the best way to handle a 404 error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, servlets, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel with Spring Boot and Jetty as embedded server.

I have a RouteBuilder that is defined with the following routes:

```
    onException(Exception.class)
             .handled(true)
             .process(new ErrorProcessor());

    rest("/mysvc/requests/{id}")
            .consumes("application/json")
            .produces("application/json")
            .get()
            .to("direct:processMyRequest");

    from("direct:processMyRequest")
            .log("Hello World");
```

When I hit my REST endpoint with a request like `GET /mysvc/requests/123`, I get a valid response `Hello World` back.

In the case where I hit a wrong endpoint like `GET /mysvc/requests` (without providing an id), I simply get a response code `404` with the following response body:

```
{
  url: "/mysvc/requests",
  status: "404",
  message: "Not Found",
  servlet: "CamelServlet",
}
```

I have noticed that there is no exception caught by the `onException` clause and neither is my `ErrorProcessor()` called. Why is this the case?

How can I ensure that such errors are caught by the `onException` clause?

Comment: Can you include the code for `ErrorProcessor` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume that not only your `onException` is not called, but also your REST route because **your request does not match the path** (missing ID).

Therefore, I assume that the standard error handling kicks in that returns a 404 because there is **no route to answer the request**.

If you want to catch these requests, you have to **create a route that listens to `/mysvc/requests`**.